# opening a text file and building a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

Need to write a function that takes an open file as the only parameter and returns a dictionary that maps a string to a list of strings and integers.

each line in the text will have a username, first name, last name, age, gender and an e-mail address. The function will insert each person's information into a dictionary with their username as the key, and the value being a list of [last name, first name, e-mail, age, gender].

basically what im trying to do is open a text file that contains this:

```
           ajones Alice Jones 44 F alice@alicejones.net
```

and return something like this:

```
          {ajones: ['Jones', 'Alice', 'alice@alicejones.net', 44, 'F']}
```

so far i have done this, but is there any other easier way?

```
def create_dict(file_name):
    '''(io.TextIOWrapper) -> dict of {str: [str, str, str, int, str]}

    '''
    newdict = {}
    list2 = []
    for line in file_name:
        while line:
            list1 = line.split() #for a key, create a list of values
    if list2(0):
        value += list1(1)
    if list2(1):
        value += list1(2)
    if list2(2):
        value += list1(3)
    if list2(3):
        value += list1(4)
    newdict[list1(0)] = list2

    for next_line in file_name: 
        list1 = line.split()
        newdict[list1(0)] = list1 
    return newdict


def helper_func(fieldname):
    '''(str) -> int
    Returns the index of the field in the value list in the dictionary
    >>> helper_func(age)
    3

    '''

    if fieldname is "lastname":
        return 0
    elif fieldname is "firstname":
        return 1
    elif fieldname is "email":
        return 2
    elif fieldname is "age":
        return 3
    elif fieldname is "gender":
        return 4
```

Comment: Your code isn't even correct, you're using `()` instead of `[]` on `list1` for indexing. And `is` operator is used for identity check not equality.

Comment: also value is undefined here so it would raise an error on `value += ...`

Comment: this might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file_name:
        lineData = line.split() #for a key, create a list of values
        my_dict[lineData[0]] = lineData[1:]
```

is a little easier i think ... although Im not sure if thats doing what you want ...

Comment: That will loop forever on `while line`, though I guess the example also did this.

Comment: yeah my bad for copy/paste... there fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly easier ways to build your dictionary:

```
d={}
st='ajones Alice Jones 44 F alice@alicejones.net'
li=st.split()
d[li[0]]=li[1:]

print d
# {'ajones': ['Alice', 'Jones', '44', 'F', 'alice@alicejones.net']}
```

If you want to change the order of the fields, do so as you are storing them:

```
d={}
st='ajones Alice Jones 44 F alice@alicejones.net'
li=st.split()
li2=li[1:]
d[li[0]]=[li2[i] for i in (1,0,4,3,2)]

print d
# {'ajones': ['Jones', 'Alice', 'alice@alicejones.net', 'F', '44']}
```

Or, just use named tuples or a dictionary rather than a list for the data fields.

One you have that part right, you can use it with your file:

```
# untested...
def create_dict(file_name):
    newdict = {}
    with open(file_name) as fin:
       for line in fin:
           li=line.split()
           li2=li[1:]
           li2[2]=int(li[2])
           newdict[li[0]]=[li2[i] for i in (1,0,4,3,2)]

    return newdict
```

Comment: @user2976886: Just try the function I wrote with your filename.

Comment: the `(1,0,4,3,2)` is how your reorder the fields to `last, first, email, gender, age`  It is the index of the first list read from the file

Comment: I use the methods in the first two parts in the function. No, you don't have to type them -- just use the function `create_dict` and see if that works. Smoke will not come out of the computer if it does not work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 2.7+, you can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{l[0]: l[1:] for l in (line.rstrip().split(' ') for line in f)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the first answer, here is the slightly different version to match the spec:

```
file=open('filename', 'r')
{username: [lname, fname, email, int(age), sex] for username, fname, lname, age, sex, email in (line.rstrip().split(' ') for line in file)}
```